# "Do While" code doesn't loop through directory - only sees one file

Tags: excel, vba

My `Do While` loop is meant to loop through all the files in the directory, but it only ever sees one file.

```
For x = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NumNF").Range("a1")

    numb_nota = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("controle").Range("C" & x).Value
    Name = "Nota Fiscal P&G número " & Left(numb_nota, 9) & ".PDF"

    Directory = "C:\Users\andrade.br\Documents\Test\"
    Filename = Dir(Directory & "*.PDF")

    Do While Filename <> ""

        If Name = Filename Then

            .Attachments.Add Directory & Filename
        End If

    Loop
Next
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Thank you for helping me, i'm looping in a folder with several PDF files, you are right, i just miss a  'Filename = Dir()'  =).

Comment: You don't need to loop - for each value of `x` you are only looping to make sure that a **single** file exists, so just process that single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop only sees one file, because you are only executing `Dir` once (to get the first file).  To make your loop work, you need to set `Filename = Dir()` to retrieve the next file.

```
For x = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NumNF").Range("a1")

    numb_nota = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("controle").Range("C" & x).Value
    Name = "Nota Fiscal P&G número " & Left(numb_nota, 9) & ".PDF"

    Directory = "C:\Users\andrade.br\Documents\Test\"
    Filename = Dir(Directory & "*.PDF")

    Do While Filename <> ""

        If Name = Filename Then

            .Attachments.Add Directory & Filename
        End If
        Filename = Dir() ' retrieve the next file name
    Loop
Next
```

---

However, because you are only ever processing a single file, the code can be drastically simplified to:

```
Directory = "C:\Users\andrade.br\Documents\Test\"
For x = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NumNF").Range("a1")
    numb_nota = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("controle").Range("C" & x).Value
    Filename = Directory & "Nota Fiscal P&G número " & Left(numb_nota, 9) & ".PDF"

    If Dir(Filename) <> "" Then
        .Attachments.Add Filename
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @YowE3K, i just miss Filename - Dir in my code... now it works properly... thanks !!!

Comment: @BrunoWilsondeAndrade Hi Bruno - if you feel this answer is sufficient, you should mark it as a correct answer by clicking that gray check mark next to the post.

Comment: Sorry.. I didn’t know that I should click that check mark!